# farsi language for direction steps

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to change the language of the mapbox direction steps to Farsi.

I used this method but it does not work for Farsi language. Help me please. thank you.

```
map.addControl(new MapboxDirections({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
language: 'fa'
```

}), 'top-left');

Comment: Not all the languages in the world are supported: [https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/directions/#instructions-languages](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/directions/#instructions-languages)

Comment: Is there a way that I can manually translate and change each of the step words (Drive northwest, Turn right onto ...)?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Is there a way that I can manually translate and change each of the step words (Drive northwest, Turn right onto ...)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Mapbox Directions API.